# Wont allow me to read in .csv file in blender

Tags: python, file, csv, path

I have encountered a problem in Blender 2.69 whilst scripting in Python. When I try to read in a `csv` file, it throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CelestialData.csv'
```

The code is:

```
import csv
...
starsFile = csv.reader(open('CelestialData.csv','r'))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use an explicit path to `CelestialData.csv` (e.g. `C:\Users\Ollington\Documents\CelestialData.csv` or `/home/Ollington/CelestialDatacsv` depending on your choice of OS).

Comment: Even with the explicit path, it throws the same error, really stumped with this, feels like I've tried everything!

Comment: If you think the file is there and Python thinks it isn't, odds are Python is right.  Before that line, add `import os` and `print os.getcwd()` to see what directory you're in, and `print os.listdir(".")` to see what files are there.

Comment: Did you use a raw string for your file path? If not, did you double the backslashes (assuming a Windows system)?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, it seems like I wasn't using the 100% correct explicit path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the 80's microsoft choose to use the `"\"` char for directory separation, instead of common `"/"` used in other Operating systems.

The matter is that the `"\"` character was already used in C language, and that behavior is copied in Python, as an escaping character inside strings. So, whenever a Python expression finds an string containing, for example, the sequence `"\t"`, that is interpreted as  a single character instead of separated `"\"` and `"t"` characters (`<tab>` which  is encoded with the number "9").

There are 3 ways to deal with this from Python:

1. Use the "/" character to separate directories and files, regardless of being on windows
2. Use a doubleforward slash, each time a forward slash is present (so, `"\\t"` instead of `"\t"`, or
   `"\\Documents\\CelestialData.csv"` instead of `"\Documents\CelestialData.csv"`)
3. Use the `r` prefix for quotes of strings - this way, Python treats the following string
   as "raw", and all `"\"` inside it are treated literally, instead of interpreted as 
   escaping the next character. e.g.: `r"\Documents\CelestialData.csv"`

I think the first option will be easier for you.